# Why do I lose the session information on redirect in Flask app?

Tags: python, session, flask

I was following one of cs50's lectures and writing the same code in vscode as in the lecture. For some reason it works in the course's ide but when it is in vscode on my PC the session forgets the input after redirection. Where is the problem and Is it possible to fix it?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'randomkey'
Session(app)


@app.route('/')
def tasks():
    if 'todos' not in session:
        session['todos'] = []
    return render_template('tasks.html', todos=session['todos'])


@app.route('/add', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('add.html')
    else:
        todo = request.form.get('task')
        session['todos'].append(todo)
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?  I have observed the same issue with flask and Chrome.  Strangely the problem does not occur with chromium based Edge.